# Usar string para referenciar variável

Tags: c#, string, variáveis, parâmetros

Desejo passar para a função `execSQL` o nome da variável que desejo utilizar em
`base.consulta()` e a partir da *string* SQL, passar diretamente a variável para a função `base.consulta()`, ou seja, passar a variável que possui o mesmo nome da *string*.

Um exemplo para vocês terem uma ideia do que eu estou querendo.

**OBS:** Sei que da forma que está não funciona e sei o porquê.

```
// variáveis com algum SQL
string sqlConsultaEspecifica = "...";
string sqlMonitoramento = "...";
string sqlVerificacao = "...";

function execSQL(string sql = "sqlMonitoramento") {
  // ...
  // realizar algumas ações aqui
  // ...
  return base.consulta(sql);
}
```

É possível fazer isso? Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Cria uma classe, adicione os comandos sql em constantes, ao chamar a função passe a constante no parâmetro, equivalente ao que o @Maniero disse em baixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada essa sintaxe não é C#.

Sempre é possível construir um mecanismo sofisticado que permita isso. Mas pra que?

Uma das formas é usar reflexão, porém quase 100% dos casos que a pessoa usa reflexão está fazendo algo errado. É uma complicação tremenda, uma perda enorme de performance, chance de falhas, de inseguranças para um ganho que muitas vezes é pequeno ou zero. Posso quase te garantir que esse caso é zero.

Onde está a chamada desse método `execSQL()`? É ali onde vai definir o que passar. Se o método já sabe o que ele quer, então não faz sentido usar isto.

Se essas variáveis são locais a um método, faz zero sentido em tentar fazer algo assim. Se as variáveis são do objeto é bem simples:

```
void ExecSQL() {
    ...
    return base.consulta(sqlMonitoramento);
}
```

Se for variável local a reflexão não funciona. Se for variável de classe ou instância a reflexão é desnecessária, ganho zero.

Se quer fazer coisas diferente, passe a `string` diferente.

```
void ExecSQL(string sql) {
    ...
    return base.consulta(sql);
}
```

Aí para chamar você passa, por exemplo:

```
ExecSQL(sqlMonitoramento);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StringParameter.cs).

Esse código é bem esquisito e pode ter uma falha arquitetural aí. Não posso afirmar porque não tem contexto.

Comment: Eu pensei em algo usando `Enum, Description` e um método de extensão, mas me fiz a mesma pergunta "Sempre é possível construir um mecanismo sofisticado que permita isso. Mas pra que?" e também achei que seria um pouco gambiarra :p

Comment: Essa solução já parece um pouco melhor que reflexão e pode ter sentido, mas neste caso ainda não vi motivo.

Comment: Essa função fica na DAO onde eu também adiciono algumas variáveis com os sql que irei utilizar. E na parte do Controller eu chamo essa função execSQL passando o nome da variável que contém o sql desejado.

Comment: Ou seja, é simples, e você quer complicar?

Comment: Estava pensando em "simplicar". Uma função para chamar qualquer sql cadastrado.

Comment: Não, você está complicando, o que eu fiz é o mais simples que existe.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter a valor de uma variavel de algum objeto é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

Imagine um objeto de nome "Teste", com 2 propriedades (Descricao e Nome).

Digamos que eu queira pegar o valor de alguma desses duas propriedades, mas ainda não sei qual, então segue um código exemplo com uma das maneiras de resolver isso.

```
Teste teste = new Teste()
        {
            Descricao = "Descrição aqui",
            Nome = "nome aqui"
        };

        string valorDesejado = teste.GetType().GetProperty("Descricao").GetValue(teste, null).ToString();
```

Dentro do "GetProperty()" vai o nome da variavel que eu quero pegar o valor. Então basta adaptar.

Comment: Mas você sabe qual é a propriedade aí, está bem explícito no código. Assim como na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

```
public void execSQL(string sql)
{
    //A variável "valor" vai estar com o valor da variável que você passou como parâmetro.
    //O objeto "classe" deve ser o objeto que possui a sua variável "sql"
    string valor = teste.GetType().GetProperty(sql).GetValue(classe, null).ToString()   
}
```

A chamada para o método ficaria assim:

```
//Aqui você iria passar a variável que gostaria de passar o nome para o método, porém ela deve ser visível para esse escopo
execSQL(nameof(sqlMonitoramento));
```

Comment: Veja minha resposta. Muito mais simples e faz exatamente a mesma coisa.